# MinitTest Spec confusion over second parameter

Tags: ruby, minitest, specifications

I'm new to BDD and I'm trying to play with MiniTest Spec:

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Car
  attr_accessor :type

  def initialize(type)
    @type = 'petrol'
  end
end


describe Array do 
  it "must be diesel" do
    Car.new('diesel').type.must_equal 'diesel'
  end
end
```

This is great - running this I get the following output:

```
Failure:
test_0001_must_be_diesel(ArraySpec):
Expected "diesel", not "petrol".
```

Which makes sense - "Expected diesel, not petrol" is exactly what I'm expecting. If I place a second parameter in my `must_equal` statement (which I assume is the message I want to return on failure) - I get an odd result:

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Car
  attr_accessor :type

  def initialize(type)
    @type = 'petrol'
  end
end


describe Array do 
  it "must be diesel" do
    Car.new('diesel').type.must_equal 'diesel', 'it must be a diesel'
  end
end
```

Running this I get:

```
1) Failure:
test_0001_must_be_diesel(ArraySpec):
it must be a diesel.
Expected "petrol", not "diesel".
```

For some reason, now it says "Expected petrol not diesel". So it seems that adding in what I assume is a message parameter (as it is in the Test Unit version) is making the assertion flip around.

Is the idea of a message param in the speccing framework void?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's been some inconsistency in how MiniTest::Spec handles multiple arguments. It appears to have been fixed in https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/commit/cd4fe89b0057edc2258876ad8c5f5e7e722f73c2.

Just install the latest version of MiniTest from RubyGems and you should be fine:

```
gem install minitest
```

Then add this on the top of your file to use the gem:

```
gem 'minitest'
```

Comment: Ah ha! I tried answering this question by looking at the source code, but I could for the life of me not figure out how the code would lead to the behavior the OP is describing. Now I know why: it doesn't, I was looking at the fixed version :-)